# Capturing Value from Inconsistent RegEx Pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of server events that are very inconsistent.

```
logs = ['event on SRVDC1.acme.loc created medium alert TS Gateway login failure.',
        'event with source 10.10.13.1 by john.smith on SRVDC1.acme.loc created medium alert More Than 3 Failed Login Attempts Within 1 Hour .',
        'authentication event with process lsass.exe, source 192.168.254.13:63000, by thomas on SRVDC1.acme.loc created medium alert Logon Failure - Unknown user or bad password.',
        'iam event by ANONYMOUS LOGON on SRVDC2.acme.loc created medium alert Computer account added/changed/deleted..']
```

There is a certain pattern to it though:

1. An event (always present) - either with a modifier e.g., authentication, iam, etc. - or simply event.
2. With a source IP (not always present)
3. On a domain (always present)
4. By an actor (not always present)
5. Alert severity (always present) - e.g., medium alert, high alert, etc.
6. Alert name (always present) at the very end of the string

I need to extract the alert name, domain name, ip, and actor. I've managed to extract the alert name and domain name, which are a constant, but I can't figure out how to extract the ip and actor since they are not always present. My idea is to replace them with a  ' - ', but so far my attempts have been a failure.

```
host_list = [re.search('(?<=on).*?(?=created)',log).group() for log in logs]
alert_list = [re.search('(?<=alert).*?(?=\.)',log).group() for log in logs]
source_ip_list = [' - ' if '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.' not in re.search('\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.',log) else re.search('(?<=source).*?(?=\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.)',log).group() for log in logs]
actor_list = [' - ' if 'by' not in re.search('by',log) else re.search('(?<=by).*?(?=on)',log).group() for log in logs]

print(host_list)
print(alert_list)
print(source_ip_list)
print(actor_list)
```

Current output

```
    source_ip_list = [' - ' if 'by' not in re.search('\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.',log) else re.search('(?<=source).*?(?=\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.)',log).group() for log in logs]
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

Expected Output

```
[' SRVDC1.acme.loc ', ' SRVDC1.acmes.loc ', ' event with process lsass.exe, source 192.168.254.13:63000, by thomas on SRVDC1.acme.loc ', ' SRVDC2.acme.loc ']
[' TS Gateway login failure', ' More Than 3 Failed Login Attempts Within 1 Hour ', ' Logon Failure - Unknown user or bad password', ' Computer account added/changed/deleted']
[' - ','10.10.13.1',' - ','192.168.254.13',' - ']
[' - ','by',' - ','by','by']
```

Comment: `'NoneType'` means you do not have a match so you cannot access `.group()` before actually getting  a match.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yes sir, I agree. But I wanted to replace that NoneType void with a ' - ' so there is something there to be added to the list. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can use `:=` (walrus) operator to assign the search result to a variable and then check it if it isn't `None`:

```py
import re

logs = ['event on SRVDC1.acme.loc created medium alert TS Gateway login failure.',
        'event with source 10.10.13.1 by john.smith on SRVDC1.acme.loc created medium alert More Than 3 Failed Login Attempts Within 1 Hour .',
        'authentication event with process lsass.exe, source 192.168.254.13:63000, by thomas on SRVDC1.acme.loc created medium alert Logon Failure - Unknown user or bad password.',
        'iam event by ANONYMOUS LOGON on SRVDC2.acme.loc created medium alert Computer account added/changed/deleted..']

host_list = [re.search(r'(?<=on).*?(?=created)',log).group() for log in logs]
alert_list = [re.search(r'(?<=alert).*?(?=\.)',log).group() for log in logs]
source_ip_list = [m.group() if (m:=re.search(r'\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+', log)) else ' - ' for log in logs]
actor_list = [m.group() if (m:=re.search(r'(?<=by).*?(?=on)', log)) else ' - ' for log in logs]

print(host_list)
print(alert_list)
print(source_ip_list)
print(actor_list)
```

Prints:

```
[' SRVDC1.acme.loc ', ' SRVDC1.acme.loc ', ' event with process lsass.exe, source 192.168.254.13:63000, by thomas on SRVDC1.acme.loc ', ' SRVDC2.acme.loc ']
[' TS Gateway login failure', ' More Than 3 Failed Login Attempts Within 1 Hour ', ' Logon Failure - Unknown user or bad password', ' Computer account added/changed/deleted']
[' - ', '10.10.13.1', '192.168.254.13', ' - ']
[' - ', ' john.smith ', ' thomas ', ' ANONYMOUS LOGON ']
```